# How Do Pass a File Path stored in Database to Flash in ASP.NET MVC (VB.NET)

Tags: flash, model-view-controller

I am using JW Player in an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm trying to pass file path from database.

param name="flashvars" value="file=<%ResolveUrl(item.VideoPath)%>&image=preview.jpg"

I get nothing for the file path. How can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an equals sign after the %, like so:

```
param name="flashvars" value="file=<%=ResolveUrl(item.VideoPath)%>&image=preview.jpg"
```

Comment: Thanks. Wow...I looked at that line a million times.